# how to open the app in another activity after login android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-lifecycle

I'm new to Android development and I'm making a simple app where the user has to login and it goes to a different screen. When the user first opens up the app they will be prompted with the `MainActivity` and if login successful they will move to `activity2`. I want to know how after the user logins and then shuts down the app and opens it again it will take them directly to `activity2`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using firebase to login/auth the user then use the following code:

```
FirebaseUser user1 = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                if (user1 == null) {
//If not signed in
                    Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, Login.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                } else {
//if signed in
                    Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-conditional) is a good example of it by using fragments and navigation component

Comment: This should be a comment

Answer (score 0):

Use **SharedPrefernces** for storing the login information. For example, if the user has successfully logged in then store an identifier in **SharedPrefrenc**e. When the user opens the app next time first check if the user has logged in previous session then take the user directly to your **MainActivity**